# Converting HTML to Image getting java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Tags: java, io, filereader

```java
import gui.ava.html.Html2Image;

public class ToImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File inputFile = new File("C:\\Users\\sam\\Desktop\\index.html");
        Html2Image imageGenerator = new Html2Image();
        imageGenerator.getParser().load(inputFile);
        imageGenerator.getImageRenderer().setAutoHeight(false);
        imageGenerator.getImageRenderer().saveImage(new File("C:\\Users\\sam\\Desktop\\new.png"));
    }
}
```

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:159)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.Lexer.zzRefill(Lexer.java:1634)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.Lexer.yylex(Lexer.java:1865)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.CSSParser.next(CSSParser.java:1798)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.CSSParser.la(CSSParser.java:1810)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.CSSParser.stylesheet(CSSParser.java:159)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.CSSParser.parseStylesheet(CSSParser.java:89)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StylesheetFactoryImpl.parse(StylesheetFactoryImpl.java:78)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StylesheetFactoryImpl.parse(StylesheetFactoryImpl.java:95)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StylesheetFactoryImpl.getStylesheet(StylesheetFactoryImpl.java:174)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StyleReference.readAndParseAll(StyleReference.java:123)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StyleReference.setDocumentContext(StyleReference.java:107)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.swing.Java2DRenderer.setDocument(Java2DRenderer.java:317)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.swing.Java2DRenderer.getImage(Java2DRenderer.java:265)
    at com.htmltopdf.HtmlToPdfConverter.ToImage.main(ToImage.java:35)
```

I am not able to find the why this is happening, Everything seems to work fine.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: could you please provide whole error stacktrace?

Comment: @OlehKurpiak Done

Comment: There are 2 calls to imageGenerator.getImageRenderer(), are they returning the same object? From https://www.javatips.net/api/easyjasub-master/easyjasub-lib/src/main/java/com/github/riccardove/easyjasub/html2image/Html2ImagePngRenderer.java it seems the correct way to doing it is Html2Image.fromFile(...).getImageRenderer().setAutoHeight(false).saveImage(...)

Comment: the stack trace does not correlate to the code.  there is no call to `getImage()` in the code you showed.

Comment: @jtahlborn please see the line number 265

Comment: @Jayr Well did the changes and it's working but by image file contains gibberish characters. Can you help me with code, it will be really helpful.

Comment: Hi @DeepakKumar the code that I gave worked for me, using version 2.0 of Html2Image